# NetBeans 6.9.1 Java Application won't compile/run

Tags: java, netbeans, cross-platform, desktop-application, netbeans-6.9

I just downloaded the latest version of Netbeans - 6.9.1. I've been using 6.8 for some time for my PHP and HTML development on websites and whatnot. My business partner needs a cross-platform desktop application developed and so I figured that Java would be the way to go.

**Here's my problem** - I downloaded the 6.9.1 version of NetBeans with all languages included, as well as the latest Java Development Kit (64bit). After installing those I started up a brand-spankin'-new Java desktop application project in Netbeans. After looking at it and getting used to the GUI I hit the compile/run button (keep in mind that I did not change ANY code at all, this is just the default bit of code that Netbeans produces when you create the Java Desktop App project); it then said it compiled, but with errors and asked if I wanted to run it anyway. I clicked 'Yes', but nothing happens.

What's the deal? Why won't the application compile properly? I've not edited ANYTHING in the code or GUI at all, so I can't imagine what the problem is.

The error message (NetBeans Output) is as follows:

```
run:
Oct 28, 2010 1:06:48 AM org.jdesktop.application.Application$1 run
SEVERE: Application class lsicontentcreator.LSIContentCreatorApp failed to launch
java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code
    at lsicontentcreator.LSIContentCreatorView.<init>(LSIContentCreatorView.java:50)
    at lsicontentcreator.LSIContentCreatorApp.startup(LSIContentCreatorApp.java:19)
    at org.jdesktop.application.Application$1.run(Application.java:171)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:209)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:597)
    at             java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
    at     java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.Error: Application class     lsicontentcreator.LSIContentCreatorApp failed to launch
    at org.jdesktop.application.Application$1.run(Application.java:177)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:209)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:597)
    at     java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code
    at lsicontentcreator.LSIContentCreatorView.<init>(LSIContentCreatorView.java:50)
    at lsicontentcreator.LSIContentCreatorApp.startup(LSIContentCreatorApp.java:19)
    at org.jdesktop.application.Application$1.run(Application.java:171)
    ... 8 more
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 10 seconds)
```

So, what's the dealio? A problem with the JDK? Something messed up with my NetBeans install? Some other SDK/Library/Framework I need to install? I've positively NO clue why the default project code doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, apparently I did accidentally modify the code or whatnot. I created a new Java Desktop App project with NetBeans, hit the compile/run button, and it ran just fine.

My apologies.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like byte code has been generated to say that the source could not compile.

Fix the basic errors first.

Comment: I'm aware that there are errors, but I've no idea what or where they are. This is the default application code that NetBeans produces for a new Java Desktop Application with absolutely NO changes to either the forms or GUI; and as such I don't know where the problem lies or even where to begin looking.

Comment: I've not done ANY Java programming before, I was trying to run the default app code just to see what it looked like. Why the default code doesn't work is beyond me - you'd think that the project they make for you would be a FUNCTIONING place to start from..

Comment: They probably did.  It is a power tool - occasionally power tools backfire in the hands of beginners.